# CIColorCube - Adjust the level of influence

Tags: ios, cifilter

I'm trying to apply the processed 3dLUT png to image through CIColorCube. It's ok.
But it seems to be hard to adjust the level of influence, ex: from 0.0 -> 1.0 as origin image -> fully effected image.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, accepted solution: adjust levels of preset manually via Lightroom, generate up to 9 levels & apply to app :)